# i am getting an error while i am updating my data using express node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i am trying to update my category name but when i click on the submit button it gives me an error however i tested my code using postman and it actually updated but in that case i have to pass the product's id manually.

the callback function of the update category:

```
    exports.updateCategory = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('GET update CATEGORY /update-category');

    if (!req.body) {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({ message: "Data to update can not be empty" })
    }

    const id = req.params.id; //req.body.id >> body means in the html/ejs file the name should be id

    categorySchema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { userFindAndModify: false })
        .then(data => {
            if (!data) {
                res.status(404).send({ message: `Cannot Update user with ${id}` })
            }
            //updating the data
            else {
                res.render('category/edit_category.ejs', {
                    category: data //variable that i am going to use is category in the ejs
                })
            }

        })

    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error update user information" })
    })


}
```

the update form >>

```
    <form action='<%=`/halalMunchies/update-category/${category._id}`%>' method="post">
.
.
.
<label class="control-label" for="categoryName"> Category Name </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
        <input id="categoryName" class="form-control" value="<%= category.categoryName%>" name="categoryName" required autofocus="autofocus" />
```

the router.js

```
    //PUT UPDATE CATEGORY

router.put('/update-category/:id', categoriesController.updateCategory);

router.get('/update-category/:id', categoriesController.updateCategory);
```

the error message on page is :

```
Cannot POST /halalMunchies/update-category/618632e3a5ad00fa5368ad5c
```

Comment: And what is the actual error you get?

Comment: the error message on the web is Cannot POST /halalMunchies/update-category/618632e3a5ad00fa5368ad5c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you did not provide a `post` endpoint in your router. Since you're using the `post` method in your form, you need to add the following in your router.js:

```
router.post('/update-category/:id', categoriesController.updateCategory);
```

Comment: thanks so much Eol, it works. but i have one more question plz, i want after i click on the submit btn in the update page, i want it to direct me to another page.

Comment: Happy to help - since this seems to be a new question, can you describe this in a new one?

Comment: yes sure i will post this question but can you plz help me with this problem . https://stackoverflow.com/q/69870869/15454800